# React telling me my variable is undefined when I try to display list contents

Tags: reactjs, json

I've been trying to display the contents of a list using JSX in React. My server side is flask and serves JSON data to the react frontend. When I provide JSON data with only a simple dictionary with string keys and values, react can display it just fine, but when I try to use a list, and I've been messing around with this for 15 hours now, it just keeps saying "Uncaught TypeError: initialData.names is undefined". This error is consistent across different mehthods of requesting the data. If I choose to display initialData.names, there is an error that JSX can't display an object with keys of "name". But as soon as I try to access the data inside, it freaks out. I've never used Stack Overflow before so let me know if my question needs a different format.

**routes.py**

```
import json as JSON
from flask import render_template, jsonify
from api import app

from api.static import variables as VARS


@app.route("/regions")
def regions():
    print("REGIONS")

    '''
    data = {"data":[{
        "name": region_name,
        "url": "/regions/" + region_name
    } for region_name in VARS.region_names]}
    '''
    '''
    data = {
        "name":"ford"
    }
    '''

    data = {
        "names":[{"name":"ford"},{"name":"toyota"}]
    }
    return data
```

**Regions.js** --gets run from the main js file

```
    import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'; //ES6 js
    import {Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
    
    function Regions(){
        const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState([{}]);
        useEffect(() => {
          fetch('/regions').then(
            response => response.json()
          ).then(
            data => setInitialData(data)
          )
        });
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Select a Region</h1>
                {initialData.names.map(brand => (<h2>{brand.name}</h2>))}
            </div>
        );
   }
    
    export default Regions;
```

[Js Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmfYI.png)

Comment: try adding `?` after `initialData` like this `initialData?.names`

Comment: @Usama I added a ? after .names and it works, would you be willing to explain what the question mark does?

Comment: Its called optional chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: the code maps initialData when its empty at first, because fetching data can take few seconds, so as mentioned above, optional chaining helps checking in null values

Comment: @Usama  Thank you so much, is there anything I can do for you guys, like give karma or something? I'm not sure how this website works.

Comment: There is [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) system on Stackoverflow. And its ok, it was simple because once we also went through these errors.